# javascript get href.replace the middle string

Tags: javascript, url

my url is `http://localhost:8080/?usrType=t#52773890547536126`

i want output as `httplocalhost808052773890547536128`

i have tried this in javascript

```
config.channel = config.channel || location.href.replace(/\/|:|#|%|\.|\[|\]/g,'');
```

it gives
`httplocalhost8080?usrType=t52773890547536126`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace everything between `?` and `#` in addition to removing all those special characters.

```
config.channel = config.channel || location.href.replace(/\?.*?#|[\/:#%.\[\]]/g,'');
```

You can use the character set `[\/:#%.\[\]]` instead of all those single-character alternatives.