# javascript url params to take out center string from url

Tags: javascript, url

my current url is `http://localhost:8080/test/?usrType=t#8059433831715886`

`var channel = location.href.replace(/\?.*?#|[\/:#%.\[\]]/g, '');`

it gives an output as `httplocalhost8080test8059433831715886`

i want the output as `httplocalhost80808059433831715886`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript get href.replace the middle string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737152/javascript-get-href-replace-the-middle-string)

Comment: var channel = location.href.replace(/?.*?#|[/:#%.[]]/g, '');    like this method i want this

Answer (score 1):

Using [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor

```js
const url = new URL('http://localhost:8080/test/?usrType=t#8059433831715886')

console.log((url.origin + url.hash).replace(/[^\w]/g, ''))
```